# How to remove panel from right side of google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I get this panel on the right side of colab and do not know how to get rid of it. any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, I had a similar panel recently appear on the right side of my notebook window. I was able to fix it by going to the settings icon in the top right corner, then 'Site' > 'Default page layout' and setting it to 'Horizontal'.